# Tail bounds for partial coupon collector process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, coupon-collector

In the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), a collector gets a random *coupon* from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ at every time instance.

The original formulation usually deals with bounds on the time it takes the collector to collect *all* (distinct) coupons.

What if we define the opposite problem:

- For a time $t\in\mathbb N$ let $C_t$ denote the number of distinct coupons within the first $t$ coupons.

By looking at some coupon $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the probability that it'll be collected is $1-(1-1/n)^t$, and thus we have $\mathbb E[C_t] = n\cdot (1-(1-1/n)^t)$.

I'm interested in a lower bound $x_t$ for $C_t$; specifically,

> **For some $\delta>0$, how can we find $x_t$ such that $$\Pr[C_t<x_t]\le \delta\quad{}\mbox{?}$$**

Comment: The probability is increasing with $x_t$. Given a fixed $\delta$, the possible $x_t$ will belong to the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, x^*\}$. So if you are solving for $x^*$, you are actually obtaining an upper bound for $x_t$. Let $T_i$ be the be the time to collect the $i$-th coupon after $i − 1$ coupons have been collected. Then $C_t < x_t$, for some integer $x_t$, if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{x_t} T_i > t$. If the numbers are not too large, it is possible to search by brute force.

Comment: @BGM - I agree, but I'm looking for an analytical solution. It seems possible to prove it for $x_t\approx \min\{n,t\}/2-O(\sqrt{t\log\delta^{-1}})$ but this seems far from being tight.